# How to append an element to a list in a forall?

Tags: prolog

Basically trying to append `D` to a list in a `forall` so I can then sort this list and extract the smallest value. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
smallest_distance( W ) :-
    forall( a( S1, S2 ), ( w( S1, S2, D ), append([D], Xs, Ls ), Xs = Ls ) ),
    sort(Xs, [W|_]).
```

Comment: I think you instead firstly want to assemble a list of Ds using findall. Please add more context.

Comment: Indeed I figured out with findall, i'll add the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out with `findall` instead:

```
smallest_distance( W ) :-
    findall(D, ( a( S1, S2 ), w( S1, S2, D ) ), Ls),
    sort(Ls, [W|_]).
```

Comment: If you look at [setof/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setof/3), you might find that it sorts/dedupes for you, thus turning your 2-liner into a 1-liner.